# weird issue with clicking on a hyphen minimize button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a simple hyphen line as a minimize button and a close button:

```js
const closeButton = document.querySelector('.close-button');
const minimizeButton = document.querySelector('.minimize-button');

closeButton.addEventListener("click", closeWindow);
minimizeButton.addEventListener("click", minimizeWindow);

function minimizeWindow() {
    console.log('minimize me');
}

function closeWindow() {
    console.log('close me');
}
```

```css
.close-container {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 23px;
  top: 12.5%;
  right: 2.8%;
  z-index: 400;
}

.close-container .close-button:hover {
   color: #ff2200;
}

.close-container .minimize-button:hover {
   border-color: #ff2200;
}

.close-container .close-button:active {
   color: #ff9500;
   transform: translateY(5px);
}

.close-container .minimize-button:active {
   border-color: #ff9500;
   transform: translate(5px, 22px);
}

.close-container .minimize-button { 
  width: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid #807c8c;
  transform: translate(5px, 17px);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.close-container .close-button {
  color: #807c8c;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="close-container">
            <div id="minimize-button" class="minimize-button"></div>
            <div class="close-button">&#10005;</div>
        </div>
```

The issue is if you click right on the hyphen the listener won't detect your click!! if you click a bit lower than the hyphen symbol the click will be detected!! How can I fix this? I want a hyphen which I can click on it and a function to execute on click over the hyphen without ruining the graphic.

Comment: Because you're using `border-top` for line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix:

```
minimizeButton.addEventListener("mousedown", minimizeWindow);
```

Explanation - element moves (translate css part, i guess) before click event is finished.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event

> This differs from the click event in that click is fired after a full click action occurs; that is, the mouse button is pressed and released while the pointer remains inside the same element. mousedown is fired the moment the button is initially pressed.